# Command "pipeline_resource_s3" not working in file but works in terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, pipeline

I am logged in an EC2 instance in one of our application in AWS cloud. I am trying get the S3 address of another application.

When I execute `pipeline_resource_s3 <my_app_name>` in command line, it successfully returns the S3 address but when I execute the same line in a file, it prompts `pipeline_resource_s3: command not found`.

My file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
pipeline_resource_s3 <my_app_name>
```

Running the file using: `./test.sh`

How can I successfully run the command `pipeline_resource_s3` in the file?

Comment: Can you share the link to `pipeline_resource_s3` command.

Comment: @ChandanKumar what do you mean by "share the link"?

Comment: Any reference(AWS document) to this command.

Comment: can't find one, i'm not sure if it's  system generated command. it's like systemctl command but it's not registered in bash.

Comment: pipeline_resource_s3 is definitely not an AWS CLI Command. It looks like when you are running from the directory which contain this script it is working fine and when passed in file it's not. You need to pass full path or set a variable in your test.sh